# Diverse fonts within a single draw.io UML entity

Tags: app.diagrams.net

In the `Entity Relation | Entity` shape it is possible to mix in different fonts/styles within the same entity:

[image]

The `text style` (`CMD-E`) is:

```
strokeWidth=2;rounded=1;arcSize=10;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;align=left;fontSize=14;
```

Why then does it seem to not be possible to do likewise in a `Entity Relation | *Table*`: shape?

When changing this:

[image]

to have just the ***primary key*** in ***bold italic*** - I did select just the ***txn_id*** but *all* of the text was changed.

[image]

The *text style* (`CMD-E`) is:

```
shape=partialRectangle;top=0;left=0;right=0;bottom=1;align=left;
verticalAlign=middle;fillColor=none;spacingLeft=4;spacingRight=2;
overflow=hidden;rotatable=0;points=[[0,0.5],[1,0.5]];
portConstraint=eastwest;dropTarget=0;fontStyle=3;fontSize=9;
```

I tried various ways and a few times and have not discovered any way to have more than one font style within the UML entity. Is there a trick here I might be missing?

Comment: What is the text style for that style (ctrl/cmd+E) and copy/paste the style string that appears please.

Comment: @David Added to the question

Comment: If you select an individual row, does just that row show selected like https://www.dropbox.com/s/yrizqau9iquhyf8/Screen%20Shot%202018-10-30%20at%2022.45.40.png?dl=0 ? Are you using the online version at www.draw.io?

Comment: ah! i see. No - I was using a *single* row entry with multiple lines. The reason: I had a list of columns and adding them one at a time as individual rows was time consuming and actually somewhat problematic.